# How To Reach My Funds From My Wallet Years Ago

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

I have a wallet.dat
and a .txt file
inside this txt file
wallet number like : **L1aC2...**
and a hash like: **$bitcoin$64$a2z...**

How can I reach to my fund inside this wallet ? I kinda have some memory about password,  but I don't exactly remember.

Comment: Make a backup first, before you try anything else. Do you remember what software you used? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Im trying hashcat problem is that my password was long very long as far as I remember it was smth like
myname_wifename_surname_dd-mm-yyyy

it has many characters...
trying
??????s???????s??????s%%?s%%?s%%%%

but it seems like it will take millenia

Answer (score 0):

The text beginning with "L1aC2" could potentially be a private key for a wallet. You have the option to import it into another Bitcoin Core wallet or Electrum to check the balance.

Instructions for importing a single private key into Electrum can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66978849).

As for the hash, it is a Bitcoin Core wallet hash. Tools such as [John the Ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/) or [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) can be used to bruteforce the password.

Comment: I wish it was private key but unfortunately I figured out its just my public key, 
other one is my passphrase which is encrypted, I tried a lot of wordlists and even created a lot of combinations which ending with dates (1 TB wordlist) still no result( 
freak*n satoshi, while trying to make it so secure, he missed human error factor. 
It would be great to put smth like "I forgot my password" :)